# Facebook login open in the same tab not in popup

Tags: python, facebook, vue.js, authentication, sdk

I am trying to add facebook login to my app. I am using facebook SDK now with popup. But now I want to change it to log in by facebook login page opened in the same tab. I tried find answers in facebook for developers dosc but I didn't get it. I am quite new in JavaScript and vue.js. I am using mostly python, but now I have to find answer.
I know that I have to create href like that:

```
window.location.href = 'https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?client_id='+app_id_fb+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri_fb+'&state='+state_param_fb
```

But I do not know where to add that to change my popup login.
my social-login.js file:

```
function login_redirect(login_data){
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", 'POST');
    form.setAttribute("action", process_social_login_link);

    for(var key in login_data) {
        if(login_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", login_data[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

function fb_login(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            fb_login_redirect({access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken,
                u_id: response.authResponse.userID});
        } else {
            fb_do_login();
        }
    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : fb_app_id,
      status     : true, // Check login status
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.1'
      // version    : 'v2.8'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

facebook.py

```
class FacebookProvider(BaseProvider):

    graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s'
    graph_url_oauth = graph_url % 'oauth/%s'
    client_id = 'xxxx'
    client_secret = 'yyy'
    access_token = None
    app_access_token = None

    def verify_access_token(self, access_token, **kwargs):

        grant_type = 'client_credentials'
        try:
            response = requests.get(self.graph_url_oauth % 'access_token',
                                    params={'client_id': self.client_id,
                                            'client_secret': self.client_secret,
                                            'grant_type': grant_type})
        except Exception as err:
            raise SocialAuthenticationError('Error while connecting to oauth')

        app_access_token = response.json().get('access_token')

        if app_access_token is None:
            raise SocialAuthenticationError('Error while getting app access token')
        else:
            self.app_access_token = app_access_token

        try:
            response = requests.get(self.graph_url % 'debug_token', params={'input_token': access_token,
                                                                            'access_token': app_access_token})
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
            raise SocialAuthenticationError('Error in request: ' + err)

        response_data = response.json()
        if response_data.get('data') is None:
            raise SocialAuthenticationError('error while getting token debug')

        if response_data['data'].get('app_id') != self.client_id:
            raise SocialAuthenticationError('invalid token (app_id)')

        self.access_token = access_token

        return True
```

Can someone give me a hint how to change that code to get login in the same tab instead of popup window? Im quite new with JS.

Comment: Right now, your code doesn’t even seem to show where you are currently triggering the actual login popup. Code for `fb_login_redirect` and `fb_do_login` is missing. Not sure what exactly your python code does here, but it seems like that is only getting an _app_ access token? Anyway, this likely isn’t something you do by just switching out a line of code somewhere, it is probably going to be more complex than that. The client- and the server-side login flow have some significant differences.

Comment: use ```window.open(url, '_blank')```